# Pre-select option by fetching data from DB via PHP with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a select tag, which option values come from a database via PHP using ajax. The previously selected value is saved in the DB.

I want to display a select showing the previously selected value (which is saved in the DB).

This is the HTML code

```
<select id='country'></select>
```

This is the JS code (ajax getting all country list)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'country.php',
    scriptCharset: 'ANSI',              
    success:function(result) {
        $('#country').append(result);
    }
});
```

Let's say I want to show country which value is 27, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
url:"country.php",              
scriptCharset: 'ANSI' ,             
success:function(result){       
    $('#country').append(result);

    // Have you tried add this???
    $('#country').val(27);

   }
});
```

@thanks rahul

Comment: there is nothing like value you have to use val()

Comment: This is really quick and on the spot answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make another select with the options, and in the js you can use onchange to reload the country list.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({
url:"country.php",
scriptCharset: 'ANSI' ,
success:function(result){
    `$`('#country').append(result);
        `$`('#country').val(VALUE);
    }
});

Comment: This is also answer the question. Thanks.